# Dynamically create button event listeners from a string without overwriting

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, dom-events, deep-copy

I am using a for loop to populate an HTML table with values from an array. Each row needs a button that links to a different URL.

```
thisbutton.addEventListener("click", function(){ window.location.href = finalurl; });
```

The string `finalurl` changes each iteration of the loop. However it passes it as a reference, so as `finalurl` changes in the next loops, the event listener is still tied to it. Meaning every button on the page is then linked to this same URL.

I need a way to pass a clone inside that function, all the ways of deep copying/cloning I have found so far would require me to set a separate variable which doesn't help because this would over write as well.

Comment: Please show all the relevant code that you are using (HTML and complete function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `for` loops, *especially* when you're using any asynchronous code, take care to use `let` or `const` to avoid hoisting. Better yet, avoid `for` loops entirely, and use an Array function instead, such as `forEach`.

When declaring `finalurl` inside your `for` loop, do something like this:

```
const finalurl = '<insert url here>'
```

When you use `var`, the variable gets hoisted to the top of the function, so once the `for` loop finishes, there is still only one `finalurl` that has been reassigned multiple times, and that `finalurl` is the same one seen by all listeners you've attached.

Since `finalurl` is a primitive string, it does *not* get passed by reference - that's not the issue.